# Unable to run command on network device - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to run a single command in a firewall as a way for me to know I can run other commands as well, however I am not sure how to interpret the error message. The firewall does not have python installed as far as I know

This is the inventory file

```
[firewall]

192.168.10.2:4118 ansible_user="my firewall user here" ansible_ssh_pass="the firewall's user's password here" ansible_connection=network_cli
```

and my test playbook:

```
- name: "Disable HTTPS rule for Xcelerator Update"
  hosts: firewall
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Log in to Firebox
    raw: who
```

The error message is this:

```
TASK [Log in to Firebox] **************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/watchguard/disableHTTPS.yml:6
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 130, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 528, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/raw.py", line 41, in run
    result.update(self._low_level_execute_command(self._task.args.get('_raw_params'), executable=executable))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 889, in _low_level_execute_command
    rc, stdout, stderr = self._connection.exec_command(cmd, in_data=in_data, sudoable=sudoable)
TypeError: exec_command() got an unexpected keyword argument 'in_data'

fatal: [192.168.10.2]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

Does anyone know how to start debugging this? The device I am trying to run the playbook on is a watchguard firebox firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ansible_connection=network_cli` with `raw` module.

If your firewall is supported by network_cli, configure it properly, at least with `ansible_network_os`...

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docs/docsite/rst/network/user_guide/platform_index.rst#settings-by-platform

Comment: thank you, that got me passed the error. My device is not in the list you pointed me to, my playbook hangs when trying the pass the raw "who" command to the firewall, is there any other variable if not network_cli I can use so the ansible is able to successfully execute the command that you know of? thanks for the help again